# CodeContracts - false positives

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I've just started experimenting with CodeContracts in .NET 4 on an existing medium-sized project, and I'm surprised that the static checker is giving me compile-time warnings about the following piece of code:

```
public class Foo
{
   private readonly List<string> strs = new List<string>();

   public void DoSomething()
   {
       // Compiler warning from the static checker:
       // "requires unproven: source != null"
       strs.Add("hello");
   }
}
```

Why is the CodeContracts static checker complaining about the strs.Add(...) line? There's no possible way for strs to be null, right? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't have a copy of VS Premium to hand, but *that exact code* reports a problem? If so, I suggest you report it on the CodeContracts forum. That really surprises me.

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet. I see how it could fail if `Foo` were marked `[Serializable]`. But if the checker can't prove this, what *can* it prove?

Comment: Jon, yes, that exact code actually causes a problem. I pasted this class into a test project, turned on static checking, and immediately I see a warning: "Possibly calling a method on a null reference".

Comment: I've reported it to the CodeContracts forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/codecontracts/thread/25247563-6a77-461e-b591-8a2e14ddda9c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The field may be marked `readonly`, but unfortunately the static checker isn't smart enough for this. Therefore, as the static checker isn't able to infer on its own that `strs` is never null, you must explicitly tell it through an invariant:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void ObjectInvariant() {
    Contract.Invariant(strs != null);
}
```

Comment: The thing with Code Contracts is to always be explicit. It doesn't "know" anything you haven't told it.

Comment: *"It doesn't know anything you haven't told it."* 

And that is the major problem with code contracts, IMO. Way too much forced hand-holding, which results in major amounts of false positives.

Comment: To be fair, even readonly fields can be set through reflection, so in fact, `strs` *CAN* be `null`

Comment: Sure, but we can also make System.String mutable through reflection; that doesn't mean we change the world to accommodate this edge case.

Answer (score 3):

The following is valid code, which I would expect to generate the warning.

```
public class Foo 
{ 
   private readonly List<string> strs = new List<string>(); 

   public Foo()
   {
       // strs is readonly, so we can assign it here but nowhere else
       strs = ResultOfSomeFunction();
   }

   public void DoSomething() 
   { 
       // Compiler warning from the static checker: 
       // "requires unproven: source != null" 
       strs.Add("hello"); 
   } 
}
```

It's quite possible that their analyzer doesn't go so far as to make sure that you have nothing in a constructor that changes the value of `strs`. Or maybe you are somehow changing `strs` in a constructor and you don't realize it.

Comment: Did you have "Implicit Non-Null Obligations" checked?

Answer (score 1):

Little correction: Pex uses Z3, an SMT solver while Clousot (the static checker code name) uses abstract interpretation and abstract domains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not knowledgeable enough with the intricacies of .NET's object initialization semantics to answer your direct question. However, here's two tips:

1. [Microsoft Research's Pex](http://Research.Microsoft.Com/projects/pex/) can automatically generate unit tests that demonstrate exactly under what conditions a contract violation might occur. It uses the same theorem prover and static analyzer as CC does, so it's a fair bet, the two will agree.
2. Proving contracts is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, so just because CC can't *prove* that it cannot ever be `null`, doesn't mean it isn't true. IOW: CC might just be wrong and you need to help it along with a `Contract.Assume` (or, if you're feeling confident, `Contract.Assert`).

Interestingly, if you explicitly add the Object Invariant Assertion that `strs` can never be `null`, CC *is* able to prove *that* and, consequently, can also prove that `strs.Add()` will never be a null reference:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void StrsIsNotNull()
{
    Contract.Invariant(strs != null);
}
```

So, I guess my hunch #2 is correct: CC is just simply wrong in this case. (Or more precisely: the encoding of the semantics of C# into the theorem prover is incomplete.)

Comment: "Proving contracts is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem" - only very generally. Meanwhile there are a ton of commonly encountered specific cases that can be proven. As Skeet says, if it can't figure out the above, that would be weird.